# Iterating and storing thousands/millions of objects efficiently

Tags: loops, iteration, quadtree

I am working on a simulation where I need to be able to handle thousands potentialy millions of objects updating every loop. 
All of the objects need to have their logic function called (AI). 
But depending on the location of the object determines how detailed the logic will be. For example:

[working with 100 objects to keep it simple]

- All objects have a location (x,y)
- `20` objects are 500 points away
  from a 'point of interest' location.
- `50` objects are 500 points
  from the `20` objects (1000 points away).
- `30` objects are within 100
  points from the point of interest.

Now say this was a detailed city simulation with the objects being virtual citizens. 
At 6pm it's time for everyone to go home from their jobs and sleep.

So we iterate through all citizens, but I'm wanting them to do different things.

- The furtherest away objects (50) Go home from their job and sleep
  until morning.
- The closer objects (20) Go home from their job, have a
  bite to eat then sleep until morning.
- The closest objects (30) Go
  home from their job, have a bite to eat, brush teeth then sleep until
  morning.

As you can see the closer they are to the point of interest the more detailed the logic becomes.

I am trying to work out what the best and most performance efficient way to iterate through all objects would be. 
This would be relativly easy with a hand full of objects but as this needs to handle at lest 500,000 objects efficiently, I need some advice.

Also I'm not sure if I should iterate through all objects every loop or maybe it would be better to iterate through the closest objects every loop but only itereate through further away objects every 10 loops?

With the additional requirement of needing the objects to interact between other objects close to them, I have been thinking the best way to do this might be to organise them in a quadtree but I'm not sure. It seems as though quad trees are more for static content, but the objects i'm dealing with, as mentioned have a location and are required to move to other locations.
Am I going down the right track of thinking? or is there a 'better' way?

I am also working in c++ if anyone thinks its relevant.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:**

1. The point of interest changes regularly, think of it as a camera
   view.
2. Objects are created and destroyed dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quickly select objects in certain radius from particular point, then quad-tree or just simple square grid will help.

If your problem is how to store millions of objects to make iteration through them efficient, then you probably could use column based technique, when instead of having 1 million objects each having 5 fields, you have 5 arrays of 1 million elements each.  In this case each object is just an index in range 0 .. 999999.  So, for example, you want to store 1 million object of the following structure:

```
struct resident
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int flags;
    int age;
    int health; // This is computer game, right?
}
```

Then, instead of declaring `resident residents [1000000]` you declare 5 arrays:

```
int resident_x [1000000];
int resident_y [1000000];
int resident_flags [1000000];
int resident_age [1000000];
int resident_health [1000000];
```

And then, instead of, say, `residents [n].x` you use `resident_x [n]`.  Such way to store objects may be faster when you need to iterate through all objects of the same type and do something with couple of fields in each object (with the same set of fields in each object).

Comment: So array one would be closest to point, array two would be next closest... then move objects between arrays depending on how close the object was from the point? The only problem that I forgot to mention is that the point of interest changes, so there would be a lot of array swapping.

Comment: @xyz No.  Just added more details.

Comment: Sorry, I miss understood. Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: I have never come across this solution before, do you have any articles to direct me to where I can read more about this? I am a bit sceptical on how having multiple arrays can be faster. Is it that there are no objects that make this faster?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the problem down into "classes", just like in the real world. Each person's class is computed from the distance. So lower class people are far away and upper class are close. Or more correctly "far class", nearish class and "here class" or whatever you want to name them.

1) Make an array with one slot for each class. This slot will hold a "linked list" of each person in that class. When a persons class changers(social climbers), then it is very rapid to move the object to another list.

2) So put everybody into the proper classes and iterate only the classes close to you. In a proper scenario there are objects which are to far away to care about so you can put those back to disk and only reload when you get nearer.

Comment: I dont know if the computational time would be beneficial? As every loop I would need to check all objects class association to make sure they still belong to the correct class and if not change their class. `for(i=0;i<n;i++) if(citizen[i]->class == far && citizen[i]->distance >= 1000) continue; else....` unless there is something i'm missing?

Comment: Do the class change when the distance OR the class is assigned. Not in the loop. So when you set distance OR the class make a function called update class and check it there. Because the lists are linked switching classes is fast.

Comment: And yes, use linked list, there is no for loop with i integer. Use the linked list to loop it. It has to be a linked list so that classes can be rapidly changed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few questions embedded in there:
-How to deal with large quantities of objects? If there is a constant number of fixed objects, you may be able to simply create an array of them, as long as you have sufficient memory. If you need to dynamically create and destroy them, you put yourself at risk for memory leaks without careful handling of destroyed objects. At a certain point, you may ask yourself whether it is better to use another application, such as a database, to store your objects, and perform just the logic in your C++ code. Databases will provide additional functionality that I will highlight.

-How to find objects in a given distance from others. This is a classic problem for geographic information systems (GIS); it sounds like you are trying to operate a simple GIS to store your objects and your attributes, so it is applicable. It takes computation power to test SQRT((X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2), the distance formula, on every point. Instead, it is common to use a 'windowing function' to extract a square containing all the points you want, and then search within this to find points that lie specifically in a given radius. Some databases are optimized to perform a variety of GIS functions, including returning points within a given radius, or returning points within some other geometry like a polygon. Otherwise you'll have to program this functionality yourself.

-Tree storage of objects. This can improve speed, but you will hit a tradeoff if the objects are constantly moving around, wherein the tree has to be restructured often. It all depends on how often things move versus how often you want to do calculations on them.

-AI code. If you're trying to do AI on millions of objects, this may be your biggest use of performance, instead of the methodology used to store and search the objects. You're right in that simpler code for points farther away will increase performance, as will executing the logic less often for far away points. This is sometimes handled using Monte Carlo analysis, where the logic will be performed on a random subset of points during any given iteration, and you could have the probability of execution decrease as distance from the point of interest increases.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a Linear Quadtree with Morton Encoding / Z-Order indexing. You can further optimize this structure by using a Bit Array to represent nodes that contain data and very quickly perform calculations.

I've done this extremely efficiently in the browser using Javascript and I can traverse through 67 million nodes in sub-seconds. Once I've narrowed it down to the region of interest, I look up the data in a different structure. All of it still in milliseconds. I'm using this for spatial vector animation.